# Find the minimum number of segments representing a circle based on distance to perimeter

Tags: geometry

I am looking to draw circles in a script using lots of straight line segments. One thing I wanted to know is is there a formula that allows me to know the minimum number of line segments needed to draw a circle up to a threshold.

Here is an image:

[image]

The general idea:

Suppose the green line is some distance **d** that I have chosen. Then it took 9 line segments (red) at a minimum to have all the line's midpoints be less than or equal to **d** in distance to the perimeter of the circle.

Would there be an easy formula that can calculate the total number of line segments rather than some iterative algorithm to find the total number of lines?

Comment: If the goal is to keep the polygon within distance $d$ from the circle, maybe also have the vertices up to $d$ outside the circle?

Comment: The vertices are always on the perimeter its a matter of how many vertices or pairs of vertices (lines).

Comment: It's simple trigonometry. Maybe someone will answer here. You can probably find what you need on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon

Comment: Let's assume the threshold to be d, then you get that half the side is $\sqrt{r^2-(r-d)2}$

Comment: Further simplification: $\sqrt{2rd-d^2}$. The actual side will need to be the largest one that is less than this one. This may be found by calculating the largest angle to divide 360.